# Can I auto-press a button on a webpage with a URL?

Tags: html, forms, url-routing

I want to be able to auto click this form button on my webpage:

```
<input value="Approve" class="btn" title="Approve" name="apv" type="submit">
```

by modifying the Url to the page before it loads. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `<form>` `method`-attribute is `GET` it is easy. Just use something like:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/page?apv=Approve
```

If the used 'method' is something else, like `POST`. It is not possible by solely providing a 'special' URL.

Comment: This is it right here! Thanks I was using POST. Changed it to GET and got it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I created a jsbin for you to checkout.  If you visit the url with #click_approved in the url it will trigger the click.  I added an onclick="alert('woohoo!')" so you could see it working.

https://web.archive.org/web/20170613132600/http://output.jsbin.com/enuhox/1 <--- no click triggered

https://web.archive.org/web/20170613132600/http://output.jsbin.com/enuhox/1#click_approved <--- click triggered

(jsbin is down so you can no longer see the code.)

Comment: Can you rewrite this answer to include the code originally hosted on jsbin? It seems to have removed your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what exactly is the reason you need to 'auto-click' a button due to not seeing your context code. But I assume you want to submit hidden data fields through this form to redirect you to a page or somehow submit data...

An easier method would just be using the onLoad() function to call a javascript call to submit what-ever you need to get done. Ex:

```
<body onLoad="my_function();">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function my_function {
//submit data and redirect
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this, can be auto-press using form

```
<button type="button">ok</button>
```

Comment: <button type="button">Not Now</button

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
if(document.URL.indexOf("#click_approved") >= 0){ 
document.getElementById('approved_btn').click();
}
</script>
<input value="Approve" class="btn" title="Approve" name="apv" type="submit" id="approved_btn">
```

add this #click_approved  in end of url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).