# URL address that includes submit

Tags: html

I am trying to create a URL address that already has some items prefilled such as the state and city. However, when I enter the example below into the address bar, I still have to hit the submit button to submit the form to see the search results.

http://test.companyx.net:9080/Test/Test.view?state=ca&city=lax

I need a URL address that goes directly to the search results. The button that is pressed on the page is named "operation" via the source page and the value before I press it is "ok".

I have tried varying variations of
http://test.companyx.net:9080/Test/Test.view?state=ca&city=lax&operation=submit
but without success. I still have to hit the "operation" button to start the search.

Comment: Sounds like the url is fine and you need to search for the following: navigate to page and automatically click button. There are results for that. There are different approaches, depending on how pages are set up. For ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284373/can-i-auto-press-a-button-on-a-webpage-with-a-url

Comment: Could you please add some code or working link?